# Enviar Hash no e-mail e confirmar no formulário

Tags: php, laravel, hash

Eu gostaria de fazer um sistema que funcionasse assim: Para o aluno confirmar o visto da prova, ele teria que receber um código hash no seu e-mail. Se ele não souber o código, ele teria que colocar o código da prova e a resposta secreta (reposta essa que ele cadastrou no registro), colar esse código no campo do formulário e quando ele confirmar,  na tabela de provas iria aparecer o Visto dele. Meu professor teve que mudar de escola e eu estou com dúvida de como fazer isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Difícil deizer sem saber o que você já tem feito. Consegue elaborar um [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Opa amigo, como sua duvida está muito abrangente creio que você quer apenar um caminho a seguir, então aqui vai algumas dicas:

Ao cadastrar os alunos e escolas, um hash deve ser gerado, logicamente esse hash deve ser unico, pois como vai ser serielizado (enviado por email), deve ser sha1 e não encrypt ex:

```
sha1($request->input('id_escola') . $request->input('email'). config(''));
```

Em seguida você deve criar uma estrutura de notificação **olhar documentação do laravel**

```
php artisan make:notification NotificacaoAluno
```

Faça um cadastro no mail trap para testar o envio

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

No controle no método que envia ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach($alunos as $aluno)
   Notification::route('mail', $aluno->email)->notify(new NotificacaoAluno($aluno));
```

A para fechar o ciclo precisa criar a rota publica que receberá esses tokens:

```
Route::get('/provas/{tokenescola}/{tokenaluno}', 'AtividadeController@mostraProvas');
```

Att